# travis+composer repeatedly failing when loading Symfony 2.8.3

Tags: symfony, composer-php, travis-ci, zikula

> - Installing symfony/symfony (v2.8.3)
>     Downloading: 85%PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 6553600 bytes) in phar:///home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.4.37/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php on line 174
>     Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 6553600 bytes) in phar:///home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.4.37/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php on line 174

*nearly* every build of my project is failing since we updated from Symfony 2.8.2 -> 2.8.3 with this error (out of memory). If I *force* a rebuild enough times, it eventually passes, so it is obviously not a problem with the project, but with travis or composer or the combination (or Symfony, I suppose). It ONLY fails when trying to load Symfony. It seems like the problem would be widespread, but I cannot find anything on SO or issues at GH.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to correct the problem?

[log from failed build](https://travis-ci.org/zikula/core/jobs/115439589)

[composer.json file](https://github.com/zikula/core/blob/1.4/composer.json)

[.travis.yml file](https://github.com/zikula/core/blob/1.4/.travis.yml)

Comment: You should use `composer install` rather than `update` so that it just loads what's listed in your lock file rather than trying to see if anything has been updated at all.

Comment: why would this affect this issue (out of memory)?

Comment: I tried it. you can see here: https://travis-ci.org/zikula/core/builds/115512447 - the results are good. It works (yay) and builds much faster (double-yay) but I don't understand (boo!) ;-) maybe you can explain why?

Comment: When you use `composer update` it tries to find the latest update to every package in your `composer.json`. When you use `composer install` it will just install whatever is registered as installed in your `composer.lock` meaning it doesn't do all of the legwork like working out dependencies and conflicts and what not. Also, if you are using `composer update` in your travis tests then you might not be testing the same setup that you have on your local machine as the packages may have changed between your local update and this one.

Comment: thank you for the expanded info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead `composer update` You should call `composer install -o` (with optimized autloader) on your CI server.

**Running composer install will:**

- Check if a composer.lock file exists
- If not, perform a composer update to create composer.lock
- **If composer.lock exists, install the specified versions from the lock file**

**Running composer update will:**

- Check composer.json
- **Determine the latest versions to install based on your version specs** - time and memory consuming task
- Install the latest versions
- Update composer.lock to reflect the latest versions installed

Using dependences versions from `composer.lock` file will give you confidence that Your tests are performed on exactly this same dependencies as you used to development. Even if in your `composer.json` you use `dev-master` versions.

If for some reasons you want to run `composer update` on travis then disabling `xdebug` before composer install (enable it after if needed for your tests) can improve `composer` performance. `xdebug` is enabled by default on travis.

> Running Composer console commands while the php extension "xdebug" is
>   loaded reduces speed considerably. This is even the case when all
>   "xdebug" related features are disabled per php.ini flags, but the php
>   extension itself is loaded into the PHP engine. Compared to a cli
>   command run with "xdebug" enabled a speed improvement by a factor of
>   up to 3 is not uncommon.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#xdebug-impact-on-composer

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue, the workaround I used was to add the following in  `before_install` :

```
echo "memory_limit=520M" >> ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/etc/conf.d/travis.ini
```

Coming from [this issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/960#issuecomment-14506725) on travis. In free plan travis offers 3GB of memory and up to 2 cores available